# zsh:vcs_info: branch name in branch format

Tags: zsh

I use this [zsh-theme](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/pixelmuerto.zsh-theme)

in this [line](https://github.com/juanpabloaj/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/pixelmuerto.zsh-theme#L13)

```
 zstyle ':vcs_info:(sv[nk]|bzr):*' branchformat '%b%F{1}:%F{11}%r'
```

set the branch format.
In Git, when I are in master branch show

```
 [master]
```

how I can change display string from `master` to `M`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can accomplish this using just a zstyle, but you can set a hook to modify the branch variable before it is printed like this:

```
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-abbrv-master
function +vi-git-abbrv-master() {
    hook_com[branch]=${hook_com[branch]/#%master/M}
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to shorten the branch name, that is displayed. Your code above seems to be the way to go for me, however I don't really understand it. Could you elaborate a bit, e.g. how the hook works, or what the `+vi` means in the function name? Or could you give me a pointer to good documentation? Thanks, and +1!

Comment: @GeorgP. Basically, what it does is using the zsh brace expansion `${name/pattern/repl}` to substitute "master" in with "M" and storing the result in the original variable (see `man zshexpn`). You could probably use the `${name:offset:length}`-expansion.  The `+vi-` really doesn't do anything it is only the way hook-functions for vcs_info have to be named. [see the docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#vcs_005finfo-Hooks)